# regex: split a long string with tabulations and newlines

Tags: python, r, regex

Consider the following string:

```
08/07/2017Peter Praet: Interview with De StandaardInterview with Peter Praet,  Member of the Executive Board of the ECB,  conducted by Pascal Dendooven and Goele De Cort on 3 July 2017,  published on 8 July 2017ENGLISH\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\tOTHER LANGUAGES\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t(1)\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t+\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\tSelect your language\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\tNederlandsNL07/07/2017Benoît Cœuré: Interview with Le Monde and La StampaInterview with Benoît Cœuré,  Member of the Executive Board of the ECB,  conducted by Marie Charrel (Le Monde) and Alessandro Barbera (La Stampa),  on 3 July,  published on 7 July 2017ENGLISH"
```

I would like to extract the two sentences in there, namely:

- `"08/07/2017Peter Praet: Interview with De StandaardInterview with Peter Praet,  Member of the Executive Board of the ECB,  conducted by Pascal Dendooven and Goele De Cort on 3 July 2017,  published on 8 July 2017ENGLISH"`
- `"NederlandsNL07/07/2017Benoît Cœuré: Interview with Le Monde and La StampaInterview with Benoît Cœuré,  Member of the Executive Board of the ECB,  conducted by Marie Charrel (Le Monde) and Alessandro Barbera (La Stampa),  on 3 July,  published on 7 July 2017ENGLISH"`

I tried using `[\w]+(?!\\t)` but this captures the `t` in `t(1` among other stuff.

What is the proper syntax here?
Thanks!

Comment: What language and do you need to use regex, or just get the sentences?

Comment: which programming language you using? because their `regexpr` are slightly different for each. Also, are you trying to extract things from just this string? or the regexpr has to work for other similar occurrences as well?

Comment: @SamuelToh I am using Python or R (stringr). The string is actually much longer and contains similar patterns. sentences are separated by these /n/t ...

Comment: Try `\w{4,}` instead of `[\w]+`. That will eliminate matches with three or fewer characters, and I'm pretty sure `\w` is already a character class: no need for brackets.

Comment: @MadPhysicist thanks that seem to skip some words as well http://regexr.com/3gb43

Comment: In Python, you could just do `re.split` on the tabs and newlines and filter out anything with fewer than say 20 characters.

Comment: yeah, but what about honing our mad regex skills bro??? :)

Comment: That's like honing your sword skills by going to a shooting gallery :) Find a problem that would really benefit from a pure regex solution and hone away.

Comment: Here you go, split on this  `r'(?:\\[\\ntr])+(?:(?:(?!\\[\\ntr]).)*\\[\\ntr])*'` https://regex101.com/r/lNv8VO/1

Comment: With my regex, no post processing is required, no muss, no fuss. But, it's too complex for some.

Comment: @sln thanks thats great! can you please explain what you do?

Comment: Posted the explainer ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, you could split the string according to the tabs and newlines, then filter out the cruft that is too short.

```
import re

[x for x in re.split('\n\t+', long_string) if len(x) > 20]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you go, split on this

`r'(?:\\[\\ntr])+(?:(?:(?!\\[\\ntr]).)*\\[\\ntr])*'`

http://www.regex101.com/r/lNv8VO/1

Explained

```
 (?: \\ [\\ntr] )+             # The start of a block of escaped \ or n or t or r
                               # Get as many as are there (like '\n\n\r\r\t\t\n\\', etc)
 (?:                           # Cluster optional
      (?:                           # ----------
           (?! \\ [\\ntr] )              # Not an escaped \ or n or t or r ahead
           .                             # This is ok, consume this
      )*                            # ---------- 0 to many times
      \\ [\\ntr]                    # A required escaped \ or n or t or r at the end
 )*                            # Cluster end, do 0 to many times
```

---

***note***
The above regex will split text at *most* into 2 sections.

If the split content contains non-escaped r,n,t, then you could allow for
multiple splits if the text is below a certain threshold.

@MadPhysicist suggests a length of 20. I'd give it 40, and use that in the
regex by giving it a range in this section `(?:(?:(?!\\[\\ntr]).){0,20}`.

The new regex is

`r'(?s)(?:\\[\\ntr])+(?:\s*(?:(?!\\[\\ntr]).){0,40}?\s*\\[\\ntr])*'`

https://regex101.com/r/lNv8VO/3

Explained

```
 (?s)                          # Modifiers:  dot-all
 (?: \\ [\\ntr] )+             # The start of a block of escaped \ or n or t or r
                               # Get as many as are there (like '\n\n\r\r\t\t\n\\', etc)
 (?:                           # Cluster optional
      \s*                           # Optional whitespace
      (?:                           # ----------
           (?! \\ [\\ntr] )              # Not an escaped \ or n or t or r ahead
           .                             # This is ok, consume this
      ){0,40}?                      # ---------- Allow (non-greedy) 0 to 40 characters for multiple sections
      \s*                           # Optional whitespace
      \\ [\\ntr]                    # A required escaped \ or n or t or r at the end
 )*                            # Cluster end, do 0 to many times
```

Comment: mind blown. why do you have a triple `(?:(?:(?!` ? this is regex hell indeed :D

Comment: @Noobie - It's the equivalent of code block scpoing like in a language. It's easy to decipher if you look at the _formatted_ version. I've added a update note for you..

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the \n and \t characters are actually newlines and tabs. Try:

```
([^\n\t]*)
```

Then augment that to get rid of the OTHER LANGUAGES, etc.

Comment: they are not newlines and tabs I think, just literals that look like that